# Can BERT be used to train non-text sequence data for classification?

Tags: classification, sequence, bert-language-model

Can BERT be used for non-text sequence data? I want to try BERT for sequence classification problems. The data is not text. In other words, I want to train BERT from scratch. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transformer architecture can be used for anything as long as it is a sequence of discrete symbols. BERT is trained using the marked language model objective, i.e., it is trained to fill in a gap in a sequence based on the rest of the sequence. If your data is of that kind, you can train a BERT-like model on it. With sequences of continuous vectors, you would need to come up with a suitable alternative to masked language modeling.

You can follow any of the many tutorials that you can find online, e.g., from the [Huggingface blog](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train) or [towardsdatascience.com](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-bert-model-from-scratch-72cfce554fc6).